Can I navigate to a local file from Azure Devops Repo view?
I know that desktop applications can be set up to open from browser links. I think they use something like a custom uri scheme, for example: discord://blah as the link href.
I'm wondering if an extension or some method exists to open an existing local copy of a file, preferably in Visual Studio, from Microsoft Azure DevOps.
This question is the reverse of what I'm after: Can I navigate to a file from Visual studio to Azure DevOps?

AFAIK it's not possible. How is Azure DevOps suppose to know the local folder where you have checked-out the source code?

Yes, there would have to be some setup steps to let it know which local dir corresponds to the Azure Repo.

On Azure DevOps, there is no built-in option or other extensions to directly open files from local.
You can upload/push files from local to the repositories on Azure DevOps, after that, you can directly open the files on the web view.
If your projects really need this feature, you can try any of the following ways:

Reference the Azure DevOps documentation "Develop a web extension" to try to develop an extension for this feature.
Try to report a feature request on Developer Community. This will make it more convenient for the Azure DevOps engineer teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving the Azure DevOps products.


